# Issue in forming JSON with Array.push() function from the Ajax data. Formed JSON is failing to populate tbody with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web

I'm trying to put data in my `tbody` using the following code

```js
     function adaptSelectedBanks(banks) {

      console.log(banks.length);

        $(function() {

            banks.forEach(function (ba)
            {
                var count = 1;
                var ligne = $("<tr></tr>");
                ligne.append($("<td>" + count+ "</td>"));
                ligne.append($("<td>" + ba.name + "</td>"));
                ligne.append($("<td>" + ba.frais + "</td>"));
                    count++;
                $("#myrow").append(ligne);
            });
        });

    }
```

the problem is that my banks array contains 3 rows but what I get in my table is 3 row of the same data even count stay the same!

here's banks code

```js
   var banks =[];
        var bank= {};

        bank.name = "Natixis";
        bank.logo = "assets/images/2.png";
        bank.frais = "300";
        banks.push(bank);

        bank.name = "XXX";
        bank.frais = "500";
        bank.logo = "assets/images/3.png";
        banks.push(bank);

        bank.name = "YYY";
        bank.frais = "700";
        bank.logo = "assets/images/4.png";
        banks.push(bank);
```

Can you tell me what the problem?

Comment: can you share the banks json along with the markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same bank object and re-assigning its attributes. So your array has the same object 3 times. And your count variable is reset to 1 for each row, it should be initialized outside the loop, try this code

```js
function adaptSelectedBanks(banks) {
  console.log(banks.length);
  var count = 1;
  banks.forEach(function (ba) {
    var ligne = $("<tr></tr>");
    ligne.append($("<td>" + count+ "</td>"));
    ligne.append($("<td>" + ba.name + "</td>"));
    ligne.append($("<td>" + ba.frais + "</td>"));
    count++;
    $("#myrow").append(ligne);
  });
}


var banks = [];
var bank1 = {};
bank1.name = "Natixis";
bank1.logo = "assets/images/2.png";
bank1.frais = "300";
banks.push(bank1);

var bank2 = {};
bank2.name = "XXX";
bank2.frais = "500";
bank2.logo = "assets/images/3.png";
banks.push(bank2);


var bank3 = {};
bank3.name = "YYY";
bank3.frais = "700";
bank3.logo = "assets/images/4.png";
banks.push(bank3);

adaptSelectedBanks(banks);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="myrow">
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

*You are re assigning count for every row in the table, try using the **index** key of Array.forEach method.*

```
        Example: 


        var table = document.createElement('table');

        banks.forEach(function(element,index,array){
        var row = table.insertRow(index);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell1.innerText(index + 1);
        cell2.innerText(element.name)
        cell3.innertext(element.frais)
        });



        var banks = [];
        var bank1 = {};
        bank1.name = "Natixis";
        bank1.logo = "assets/images/2.png";
        bank1.frais = "300";
        banks.push(bank1);

        var bank2 = {};
        bank2.name = "XXX";
        bank2.frais = "500";
        bank2.logo = "assets/images/3.png";
        banks.push(bank2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yup! There are two problems with the code snippet you shared.
[Here's the working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vignz_pie/1dqz6t3s/20/)

1] The count variable is not increasing because it resets to 1 in every loop iteration, moving it outside the for-loop will help!

2] Forming the `bank` object dynamically with the function call-back will help you build `banks` object.

```
var banks =[];

function mySyncPush(name, logo, frais, cb){
    return cb({"name": name, "frais": frais, "logo": logo});
};

mySyncPush("Natixis", "assets/images/2.png", "300", function(bank){
    banks.push(bank);
});

mySyncPush("XXX", "assets/images/3.png", "500", function(bank){
    banks.push(bank);
});

mySyncPush("YYY", "assets/images/4.png", "700", function(bank){
    banks.push(bank);
});

console.log(banks);
```

You can actually have `mySyncPush` function in a loop provided you iterate for *name*, *logo*, *frais*, which will be the function parameters.

Note that `mySyncPush` is a [callback function](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-callbacks-explained-using-minions-da272f4d9bcd)!

Comment: Array.push is synchronous. He is just pushing the same reference 3 times on the array. So the array holds the same object 3 times with its values set to the last time. Sorry, I'm down voting because we don't want people to think array.push is asynchronous.

Comment: I'm Sorry @John, my bad! I have edited the answer right to the point. Feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: I can see the improvement, but it's an awfully complicated way to add elements to an array. `banks.push({name: "yyy", frais: "300", logo: "somelogo.png"});` is all that's needed. The mySyncPush function obfuscates the simplicity of adding an element to an array and suggests some other asynchronous context that isn't present in the OP question. I can't remove my downvote without voting this answer up, but voting it up would make it go above answers that are factually better.